# Do register reads/writes require critical section protection?

Tags: c++, concurrency, windows-mobile

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project for Windows Mobile 6 ARMV4I where I have code like this:

```
// list of CPU registers (all DWORD aligned)
typedef volatile struct
{
    // status register
    DWORD my_status;
} MY_REGS;

MY_REGS* my_regs;

// reads the status register
DWORD ReadMyStatus()
{
    DWORD status;
    // EnterCriticalSection()
    // equivalent to:
    //     status = INREG32( &my_regs->my_status );
    status = ( *( volatile unsigned long* const )( &my_regs->my_status ) );
    // LeaveCriticalSection()
    return status;
}

// sets a bit in the status register
DWORD SetMyStatus( DWORD status )
{
    // EnterCriticalSection()
    // equivalent to:
    //     SETREG32( &my_regs->my_status, status );
    ( *( volatile unsigned long* const )( &my_regs->my_status ) ) = 
        ( ( *( volatile unsigned long* const )( &my_regs->my_status ) ) | ( status ) );
    // LeaveCriticalSection
}
```

Do I need CriticalSection protection around the register reads and writes assuming they can be called simultaneously from different threads?

As I understand it on WM ARMV4I, DWORD-aligned DWORD reads/writes are atomic and volatile guarantees memory acquire/release semantics in WM. So, the CS protection should be unnecessary. Am I correct?

Comment: I do not think `volatile` guarantees anything... maybe your compiler has non-standard guarantees for it?

Comment: Yes, this is a microsoft-specific characteristic of volatile. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: for mvc this is probably working but why do you have these casts ( *( volatile unsigned long* const )?

Comment: FYI, the ARM7TDMI processor uses registers in order to disable and enable interrupt (a form of entering and leaving a critical section).  So the critical section is processor dependent.  Most likely, one or two register loads does not need a critical section.

Comment: @mgr - The casts are an expansion of Windows Mobile specific macros that I don't expect anybody to recognize. I added them to the inline-comments if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InterlockedExchange` to set a value and `InterlockedExchangeAdd` [[documentation]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910697.aspx) with zero as addend to read a value. These functions guarantee synchronized access and are available since WM 5.

Comment: Sure, but that's just another synchronization method. My question isn't how to synchronize, but rather if it is necessary at all.

Comment: Yes, it's necessary. While `volatile` assures that instructions order will not be messed with, it does not guarantee a consistent read/write architecturally. An article at http://www.jonmasters.org/blog/2012/11/13/arm-atomic-operations/ addresses some ARM specifics that compiler may or may not know about, so use of crit.section or locks would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the article. That has some very good information.